# Finding String in Cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to find a cell which contains DPD End. I want it to find the value farthest to the right because my row contains DPD End Jan, Feb, etc., so I'm looking for the most recent one, which will be located in the later columns.

I'm currently seeing an error, even when I add a wildcard:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
    Set b = .Find("DPD End*", LookIn:=xlPrevious)
MsgBox b.Column
End With
```

Comment: You're mixing up parameters; `xlPrevious` is not valid for `LookIn`. Consult the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `LookIn` which specifies the type of content in looked cells, you should use `SeachDirection` which let you specify the direction of search, as you intended.

Moreover, to look from right to left (and find the farthest/most right column), you need to specify the last cell as starting cell, here using `.UsedRange` to avoid checking blank cells as much as possible.

Please try following code (not tested):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set b = .Rows(1).Find("DPD End*", After:= .Cells(1,.UsedRange.Columns.Count), _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
End With
If Not b Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Found match in column " & b.Column & "."
Else
    MsgBox "No match found."
End If
```

NB: If your sheet do **NOT** start on 1st column, you need to add the first used column index to `.UsedRange.Columns.Count`.

Comment: Would you not need to specify the `After` parameter too?

Comment: @SJR i believe if not specified it's the top left cell by default, here A1.

Comment: @BigBen - it is, I just checked the docs, as you advised above!

Comment: There'd be nothing to do here if people did that.